# How do I commit with git when receiving error while trying to merge commit: Waiting for your editor to close the file...?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I am new to git.
I was trying to do merge commit on a new branch from the master branch.

```
git merge --no-ff newbranch
```

Then it got the below error:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... unix2dos: converting file C:/Users/user/.git/MERGE_MSG to DOS format..
```

can anyone explain why? and how to solve.

Comment: Normally it's not an error. git is telling you that it has opened an editor (or depending on the editor a tab in an existing instance) and it is waiting for you to close it before continuing. Do you have an instance of an editor, maybe opened in the background, that you have not noticed?

Answer (score 1):

Your merge operation requires to enter a comment, so git is trying to open an editor of your own which has not yet been setup.

You should issue the following command:

```bash
git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

Obviously you can change **nano** with you preferred text editor. For example **gedit** under Linux ore **notepad** under Windows.

Comment: Just make sure that it is an editor that will remain open while the file is being edited and will terminate when you close the file. I say because some GUI-based editors could open the editor in another preexisting window and terminate before you even start writing (like `kate`). `nano`, `vi`, `vim` are safe bets.